# onChange and where is the value of a selected element (jQuery Mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

How do I get the value of a selected element in the below example? The 'change' handler is being fired as expected but where on earth is the value?

JavaScrip:

```
$("#test").bind('change', function(event, ui)
{
   alert(ui.value); // ????!!!!
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="test"  data-native-menu="false">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#test").bind('change', function(event, ui) {
   alert(this.value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks that's worked. I'll accept the answer in 11 minutes :)